# Pandas: How to read contents of a CSV into a single column?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv

I want to read a file 'tos_year.csv' into a Pandas dataframe, such that all values are in one single column. I will later use pd.concat() to add this column to an existing dataframe.

The CSV file holds 80 entries in the form of years, i.e. "... 1966,1966,1966,1966,1967,1967,... "

What I can't figure out is how to read the values into one column with 80 rows, instead of 80 columns with one row.

This is probably quite basic but I'm new to this. Here's my code:

```
import pandas as pd
tos_year = pd.read_csv('tos_year.csv').T
tos_year.reset_index(inplace=True)
tos_year.columns = ['Year']
```

As you can see, I tried reading it in and then transposing the dataframe, but when it gets read in initially, the year numbers are interpreted as column names, and there apparently cannot be several columns with identical names, so I end up with a dataframe that holds str-values like

... 
1966 
1966.1 
1966.2 
1966.3 
1967 
1967.1 
...

which is not what I want. So clearly, it's preferable to read it in correctly from the start.

Thanks for any advice!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `header=None` for avoid parse years like columns names, then transpose and rename column, e.g. by [`DataFrame.set_axis`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_axis.html):

```
tos_year = pd.read_csv('tos_year.csv', header=None).T.set_axis(['Year'], axis=1)
```

Or:

```
tos_year = pd.read_csv('tos_year.csv', header=None).T
tos_year.columns = ['Year']
```

Comment: Thank you jezrael, this solved my problem right away. I hope this post can help others too, as I was googling my issue for a long time before asking a question here. Cheers!